# Как узнать список библиотек, которые используются программой(бинарём)?Какие библиотеки использует программа?

Tags: linux, библиотеки

Есть собранный бинарь, надо узнать что он подтягивает(использует) для своей работы. Точно помню, что есть такая утилита на Linux, вот почему-то не могу найти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Нашел в источнике](http://microsin.ru/content/view/550/1/):

1. Если не знаем где лежит программа - ищем её

   ```
   find / -name firefox //(или любое другое имя вашей программы)
   ```
2. переходим в директорию с бинарём и запускаем утилиту `ldd`

   ```
   ldd ./firefox
   ```

Comment: Если программа в пути (а она в пути, раз мы не знаем, где она лежит), то более стандартный вариант шага 1 — `which firefox`

Answer (score 1):

Вообще зависимость от библиотек на программерском сленге называется `dependency`

В хорошем случае зависимости даже динамические можно посмотреть через `gdb` genue debugger загружакшь прогу в отладчик и смотришь deps.

По нубский - тяп-ляп, `ldd` (list dynamic dependencies) даёт информацию о статический загруженных библиотеках.

**Добавлено спустя. Вот пример догрузки на самом простейшем паскаль варианте под винду (добавлено просто для понимания как это вообще работает)**

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses SysUtils, Windows;
// Данная функция динамический зависима от user32.dll
// Если ОС не сможет загрузить её динамический, то приложение даже не запустится.
// Это всё видит `ldd` в линуксе
// Тут есть жесткое правило для ос - внешняя user32dll по имени MessageBeep
function MessageBeep(uType: UINT): BOOL; stdcall; external 'user32.dll' name 'MessageBeep';
// А вот в этом варианте она даже не существует но догрузится после
// Это уже увидит отладчик. После выполнения операций с загрузкой SO файла
// По факту пофигу, есть-ли user32 в системе или нет, но приложение уже запущенно.
// И уже приложение решает, что делать с ошибкой если вдруг динамический, динамическая библиотека не загруженна.
type TMyFunc = function(uType: UINT): BOOL; stdcall;
var
    hLib: DWORD;
    ptrProc: TMyFunc;
begin
    MessageBeep(0);

    hLib := LoadLibrary('user32.dll');
    ptrProc := GetProcAddress(hLib, 'MessageBeep');
    ptrProc(0);
end.
```

Comment: разве ldd не даёт информацию о динамических библиотеках?
почему тогда она отображает системные либы?Почему тогда она называется list dynamic dependencies? Да и в принципе статические библиотеки, они же в бинаре записаны, насколько я понимаю

Comment: @SpaceResearcher Потому что по факту можно компилировать приложение 2мя способами, первый это - бинарный код содержится в самом приложении. Второй - ты надеешься что в системе будет некий so файл с бинарным кодом. Но это не исключает 3й вариант, когда внешний so файл, ты загрузишь после старта приложения, в самом коде.

Comment: @SpaceResearcher что второе, что третье это всё динамическая загрузка. Просто во втором варианте это делает ос (и это видит ldd), а в третьем это делает программа уже в runtime (запущенном) режиме. И вот третий вариант можно отловить только в отладчике, который де факто gdb в линуксе.